# how to check if authentication is enabled in asp.net application?

Tags: asp.net, authentication

In an ASP.net application, user can enable or disable authentication. What is the best way to check if the authentication is enabled or disabled in the Login page?
I would like to redirect user to the main page if the authentication is disable.

Comment: Who disables the authentication?

Answer (score 0):

```
            if(!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                Response.Redirect("login.aspx", true);
            }
```